# Why the present perfect tense?

Tags: present-perfect

> If you've got family, you've got drama.

Well, I think this is a fact, at least from the speaker's point of view, so I would say:

> If you get family, you get drama.

It's like if water boils, it evaporates.

So why is the present perfect tense used? and what does it add to the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general statement of truth, there are any number of ways to express this thought.  However, some are better than others.  In your second sentence you say:

> When you **get** family ...

and while this is an interesting phrasing, it doesn't really make sense.  You don't *get* (in the sense of *acquire*) family.  Your family *gets* you.

Instead you could say something like:

> Where **there is** family, **there is** drama.

This expresses the universal truth that the existence of one inevitably leads to the existence of the other.

In a similar way, "have got", as used in your first example sentence, expresses the *existence* of something rather than the *acquisition* of something.  An example:

> **I've got** two brothers.

I didn't *acquire* my brothers.  My parents (obviously) did that for me.  *Have got* is another way to say *exist*.

Note you can also use *have* instead of *have got*.

> I **have** two brothers.

Although this implies more *possession* than *acquisition*, again it actually means *they exist* (since I certainly don't *own* my siblings).

Answer (score 1):

In the present tense, “have,” “have got” are used for the same thing.
“Have” shows **ownership of something**. When somebody owns something, you should usually use the word “have.” That's why the first sentence with **have got** is correct.

Comment: To add on to that: "if you get family, you get drama" would imply that it's the *acquisition* of family that causes drama, rather than the *continued having*. That's appropriate if you're discouraging someone from joining a family, but otherwise not really.

Comment: So what about this one: "If you have a family, you have drama." ?

Comment: @user2824371 it's okay but it's more formal than _have got_. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/have-got-and-have